# Using a ADO.Net dataset on the report server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, reporting-services

I have a asp.net application that is using SSRS in the local mode. In other words it retrieves data from a database and populates ado.net datasets and parses them to the report before rendering - which is pretty standard practise.

Due to the report viewer taking too long to render the reports I am looking at using the remote mode and a report server.   The problem is that the data I use needs extra processing in C# and cannot just be retrieved directly from the database.

Are there any suggestions...

Is there a way to retrieve the data , process the data in C# then send the data ( in a datatable ) to the report server for processing in the report.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot pass data to a remote report server. ([this microsoft official agrees with me](http://www.developmentnow.com/g/115_2007_2_0_0_938469/Pass-in-a-DataTable.htm)).

I once had a similar problem and did just as suggested in the article.
(Pass the processed data back to the database, maybe using an id, and load this data in the report.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I think you are right, it is probably the simplest way to do this.